# HUE on AWS : Hive Editor needs HiveServer2 - Error creating table sample_07

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, cloudera, hue

I deployed a Cloudera EDH cluster on AWS using Quickstart and the cloudera-director executable. I followed the instructions in here :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/cloudera/welcome.html
and I used the aws.reference.conf file that comes with the Cloudera launcher. Everything works fine during the deployment, but I am having problems with HUE/Hive editor. When I go to the HUE UI I see the screen below :

[image]

And when I try to open the Hive Editor I get :

[image]

It seems to me that the source of the problem could be here :

```
InvalidConfigurationException hive.server2.authentication can't be none in non-testing mode
```

The nodes connect with each other using the auto-generated key pair file during the AWS CloudFormation launch, so there is no password configured for ssh.

I logged in to the node running hive and looked at the hive log file says this :

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.KeyProviderCache: [pool-6-thread-2]: Could not find uri with key [dfs.encryption.key.provider.uri] to create a keyProvider !!
```

and the hue log file says :

```
    [28/Jan/2016 17:22:02 -0800] models       ERROR    error syncing beeswax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/models.py", line 297, in sync
    for job in find_jobs_with_no_doc(SavedQuery):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 96, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 857, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 713, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.6.10-py2.6.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 452, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
OperationalError: no such column: beeswax_savedquery.is_redacted
[28/Jan/2016 17:22:02 -0800] models       ERROR    error syncing search
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/models.py", line 315, in sync
    from search.models import Collection
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/apps/search/src/search/models.py", line 34, in <module>
    from libsolr.api import SolrApi
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/desktop/libs/libsolr/src/libsolr/api.py", line 46, in <module>
    class SolrApi(object):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/desktop/libs/libsolr/src/libsolr/api.py", line 50, in SolrApi
    def __init__(self, solr_url, user, security_enabled=SECURITY_ENABLED.get()):
AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'get'
[28/Jan/2016 17:33:52 -0800] views        ERROR    Error in config validation by liboozie: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.44 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:w
hite;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#
525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sa
ns-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</
b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>java.lang.Uns
upportedOperationException
        org.apache.oozie.util.MetricsInstrumentation.getVariables(MetricsInstrumentation.java:333)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseAdminServlet.instrToJson(BaseAdminServlet.java:339)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseAdminServlet.sendInstrumentationResponse(BaseAdminServlet.java:396)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseAdminServlet.doGet(BaseAdminServlet.java:127)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.JsonRestServlet.service(JsonRestServlet.java:289)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter$2.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:171)
        org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:589)
        org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:552)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:176)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:86)
</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.44 logs.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.44</h3></body></html> (error 500)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/views.py", line 445, in _get_config_errors
    for confvar, error in validator(request.user):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/desktop/libs/liboozie/src/liboozie/conf.py", line 86, in config_validator
    intrumentation = api.get_instrumentation()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/desktop/libs/liboozie/src/liboozie/oozie_api.py", line 304, in get_instrumentation
    resp = self._root.get('admin/instrumentation', params)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/rest/resource.py", line 97, in get
    return self.invoke("GET", relpath, params, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/rest/resource.py", line 78, in invoke
    urlencode=self._urlencode)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/rest/http_client.py", line 161, in execute
    raise self._exc_class(ex)
RestException: <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.44 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        org.apache.oozie.util.MetricsInstrumentation.getVariables(MetricsInstrumentation.java:333)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseAdminServlet.instrToJson(BaseAdminServlet.java:339)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseAdminServlet.sendInstrumentationResponse(BaseAdminServlet.java:396)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseAdminServlet.doGet(BaseAdminServlet.java:127)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.JsonRestServlet.service(JsonRestServlet.java:289)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter$2.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:171)
        org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:589)
        org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:552)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:176)
        org.apache.oozie.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:86)
</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.44 logs.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.44</h3></body></html> (error 500)
[28/Jan/2016 17:33:53 -0800] conf         ERROR    The application won't work without a running HiveServer2.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/conf.py", line 185, in config_validator
    server.get_databases()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/dbms.py", line 151, in get_databases
    handle = self.execute_and_wait(query, timeout_sec=timeout)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/dbms.py", line 548, in execute_and_wait
    handle = self.client.query(query)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/hive_server2_lib.py", line 923, in query
    return self._client.execute_async_query(query, statement)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/hive_server2_lib.py", line 703, in execute_async_query
    return self.execute_async_statement(statement=query_statement, confOverlay=configuration)
 File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/hive_server2_lib.py", line 721, in execute_async_statement
    res = self.call(self._client.ExecuteStatement, req)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/hive_server2_lib.py", line 597, in call
    raise QueryServerException(Exception('Bad status for request %s:\n%s' % (req, res)), message=message)
QueryServerException: Bad status for request TExecuteStatementReq(confOverlay={}, sessionHandle=TSessionHandle(sessionId=THandleIdentifier(secret='r\x94N\xc0\xac\x99D\xd9\xad\xe1\xb7\x15?N\xd4B', guid='o\x1c\xe77\x06\x7fJ\x19\xaa\xd9N\xf0.\xcd[\xc2')), runAsync=True, statement="SHOW DATABASES LIKE '*'"):
TExecuteStatementResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=40000, errorMessage="Error while compiling statement: FAILED: InvalidConfigurationException hive.server2.authentication can't be none in non-testing mode", sqlState='42000', infoMessages=["*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while compiling statement: FAILED: InvalidConfigurationException hive.server2.authentication can't be none in non-testing mode:17:16", 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:326', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:102', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runInternal:SQLOperation.java:171', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:run:Operation.java:268', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementInternal:HiveSessionImpl.java:410', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementAsync:HiveSessionImpl.java:397', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:executeStatementAsync:CLIService.java:258', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:ExecuteStatement:ThriftCLIService.java:509', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1313', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1298', 'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39', 'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39', 'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56', 'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:285', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615', 'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745', "*org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.conf.InvalidConfigurationException:hive.server2.authentication can't be none in non-testing mode:32:16", 'org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.authz.HiveAuthzBinding:validateHiveServer2Config:HiveAuthzBinding.java:167', 'org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.authz.HiveAuthzBinding:validateHiveConfig:HiveAuthzBinding.java:135', 'org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.authz.HiveAuthzBinding:<init>:HiveAuthzBinding.java:83', 'org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.authz.HiveAuthzBinding:<init>:HiveAuthzBinding.java:79', 'org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.HiveAuthzBindingHook:<init>:HiveAuthzBindingHook.java:109', 'sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl:newInstance0:NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:-2', 'sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl:newInstance:NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57', 'sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl:newInstance:DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45', 'java.lang.reflect.Constructor:newInstance:Constructor.java:526', 'java.lang.Class:newInstance:Class.java:374', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.HookUtils:getHooks:HookUtils.java:60', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:getHooks:Driver.java:1294', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compile:Driver.java:407', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compile:Driver.java:305', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compileInternal:Driver.java:1110', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compileAndRespond:Driver.java:1104', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:100'], statusCode=3), operationHandle=None)
```

The sentry log file shows no errors. I also checked in the web ui and HiveServer2 is running.

Comment: Does your hive script work on commandline? if so it could be a hue issue. Most likely it's an issue with sentry.

Comment: I added some more info. I don't see any issue with sentry

Answer (score 0):

This Hive error is about not setting 'hive.server2.authentication' https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2#SettingUpHiveServer2-Authentication/SecurityConfiguration, but this is porbably related to your AWS security settings, as None should work by default.

Other errors in Hue can be ignored, these are more warnings because some apps like the Search app were disabled.